# Why can numbers be substituted by sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I often face proofs, for example the proof that every function that is continuous on $[a,b]$ is uniformly continuous, where sequences are used instead of numbers. For example for the claim above:

Assume that $f$ is not uniformly continuous, then there is a $\varepsilon >0$ and for all $\delta =1/n$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there are $x_n,x_n'\in [a,b]$ such that $|x_n-x_n'|<1/n$ and $|f(x_n)-f(x_n')|\geq \varepsilon$.

Why is that possible?

Comment: How would *you* state that a function is “not uniformly continuous”?

Comment: $x_n$ **is** a number. A sequence $(x_n)$ is a sequence of numbers.

Comment: Is it sufficient to say that $x_n, x_n'\in [a,b]$ and nothing else?

Comment: Might be worth to add to @MauroALLEGRANZA's comment that sometimes one encounters $x_n$ being written for the sequence itself as well. But here, it's clear from $x_n, x_n' \in [a, b]$ that both must be real numbers since the set $[a, b]$ contains real numbers.

Comment: if you have $x,y\in [a,b]$ it just refers to two random numbers, could you say that $x_n,x_n'\in[a,b]$ are more like random target-oriented numbers. Usually you want to achieve something trough specific sequence constructions...

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic Only in specific circumstances it refers to two *arbitrary* numbers. Namely, if you say "let $x, y \in [a,b]$. In most other cases, it means something different, e.g. "thereby we conclude $x \in [a,b]$." This is an assertion! Here you assert that you can pick $x_n, x_n'$ in that set such that they fulfill specific properties.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether this addresses your concern in general, but here is what happens in this specific case.

In this argument we are not applying (the negation of) uniform continuity to a sequence. We're applying it to a whole lot of different numbers separately. These numbers just also happen to form a sequence, and we use that sequence-ness in a *different* part of the argument to reach a contradiction.

The negation of uniform continuity says that for any $n\in \Bbb N$, there are two numbers $x_n, x_n'$ such that $|x_n-x_n'|<\frac1n$ but at the same time $|f(x_n)-f(x_n')|\geq \varepsilon$. There is no sequence here. Only numbers. There happens to be an $n$ here which we will use to make a sequence in the *next sentence* of the proof, but by then we're already done with the negation of uniform continuity. It was only ever used on numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you negate the definition of continuity, you get: "There exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$, there exist $x,x' \in [a,b]$ such that $|x-x'|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(x')|\geq \epsilon$.

So in particular, for any choice of $\delta = 1/n$, there exist $x,x' \in [a,b]$ such that $|x-x'|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(x')| \geq \epsilon$. You can choose to call these $x_n,x_n'$ instead to indicate that they were chosen to go along with $\delta = 1/n$.

Technically you need to invoke the [Axiom of Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) to choose $x_n,x_n'$ for *all* $\delta=1/n$ simultaneously. Typically this is not explicitly stated in analysis, although it is used quite frequently.